# why is spring data jpa hibernate mariadb timestamp fractional seconds truncated on insert?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

I have a column with the following definition:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME(3)")
private Timestamp timestamp;
public Timestamp getTimestamp() {return this.timestamp;}
public void setTimestamp(final Timestamp timestamp) {this.timestamp = timestamp;}
public String getFormattedTimestamp() {return Util.getFormattedTimestamp(this.timestamp);}
```

If I save the grand-parent entity (it's in a @ManyToOne relationship in another @ManyToOne relationship), the fractional seconds are always set to .000, however, if I manually insert into the table, the fractional seconds are properly retained.

The resultant table definitions is as follows:

```
MariaDB [field_server]> show columns from device_timestamp;
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                    | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| deviceTimestampReason | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| loggedIn              | bit(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| reason                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp             | datetime(3)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [field_server]>
```

Program trace indicates the following:

```
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,394 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@2aef651: insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **)]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,394 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [ws.daley.field.persistence.model.DeviceTimestamp#8]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,395 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.EnumType$EnumValueMapperSupport - Binding [0] to parameter: [1]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,395 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BOOLEAN] - [true]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,395 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [setupDataLoader]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,396 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2017-05-23 08:20:01.176]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,396 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - [8]


webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,404 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,404 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@67f8586f: insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **)]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,405 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [ws.daley.field.persistence.model.DeviceTimestamp#9]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,405 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.EnumType$EnumValueMapperSupport - Binding [1] to parameter: [1]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,405 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BOOLEAN] - [false]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,406 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [setupDataLoader]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,406 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2017-05-23 08:20:03.176]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,406 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - [9]


webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,622 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,623 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@42a057b6: insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **)]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,623 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [ws.daley.field.persistence.model.DeviceTimestamp#12]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,623 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.EnumType$EnumValueMapperSupport - Binding [0] to parameter: [1]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,623 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BOOLEAN] - [true]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,623 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [setupDataLoader]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,623 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2017-05-23 08:20:01.455]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,624 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - [12]


webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,625 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,625 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@62036b05: insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **)]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,625 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [ws.daley.field.persistence.model.DeviceTimestamp#13]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,626 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.EnumType$EnumValueMapperSupport - Binding [1] to parameter: [1]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,626 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BOOLEAN] - [false]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,626 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [setupDataLoader]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,626 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2017-05-23 08:20:03.455]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:01,626 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - [13]


webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,419 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,419 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@126320a8: insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **)]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,419 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [ws.daley.field.persistence.model.DeviceTimestamp_AUD#component[id,REV]{REV=org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity#1, id=8}]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,419 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,420 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.EnumType$EnumValueMapperSupport - Binding [0] to parameter: [2]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,420 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BOOLEAN] - [true]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,420 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [setupDataLoader]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,420 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2017-05-23 08:20:01.176]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,420 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [8]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,420 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [1]


webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,421 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,422 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@12b0440b: insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **)]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,422 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [ws.daley.field.persistence.model.DeviceTimestamp_AUD#component[id,REV]{REV=org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity#1, id=9}]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,422 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,422 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.EnumType$EnumValueMapperSupport - Binding [1] to parameter: [2]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,422 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BOOLEAN] - [false]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,422 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [setupDataLoader]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,422 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2017-05-23 08:20:03.176]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,422 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [9]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,422 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [1]


webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,439 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,440 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@76737130: insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **)]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,440 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [ws.daley.field.persistence.model.DeviceTimestamp_AUD#component[id,REV]{REV=org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity#1, id=12}]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,440 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,440 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.EnumType$EnumValueMapperSupport - Binding [0] to parameter: [2]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,440 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BOOLEAN] - [true]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,440 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [setupDataLoader]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,440 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2017-05-23 08:20:01.455]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,441 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [12]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,441 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [1]


webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,442 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,442 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@6f2a13c7: insert into device_timestamp_AUD (REVTYPE, deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id, REV) values (** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **)]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,442 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [ws.daley.field.persistence.model.DeviceTimestamp_AUD#component[id,REV]{REV=org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity#1, id=13}]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,442 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,442 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.EnumType$EnumValueMapperSupport - Binding [1] to parameter: [2]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,442 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BOOLEAN] - [false]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,442 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [setupDataLoader]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,442 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2017-05-23 08:20:03.455]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,443 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [13]
webadmin - 2017-05-23 08:20:02,443 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```

Note that the data appears to be inserted with the fractional seconds in tact. However, the following shows that no fractional seconds are sent to the database.

```
MariaDB [field_server]> select * from device_timestamp;
+----+-----------------------+----------+-----------------+-------------------------+
| id | deviceTimestampReason | loggedIn | reason          | timestamp               |
+----+-----------------------+----------+-----------------+-------------------------+
|  8 |                     0 |         | setupDataLoader | 2017-05-23 08:20:01.000 |
|  9 |                     1 |          | setupDataLoader | 2017-05-23 08:20:03.000 |
| 12 |                     0 |         | setupDataLoader | 2017-05-23 08:20:01.000 |
| 13 |                     1 |          | setupDataLoader | 2017-05-23 08:20:03.000 |
+----+-----------------------+----------+-----------------+-------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [field_server]>
```

I have included useFractionalSeconds in my jdbc.url:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/field_server?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useFractionalSeconds=true
```

And here's the SQL. No fractional seconds:

```
webadmin - 2017-05-23 19:17:05,005 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
/* conn id 1046 clock: 1495581425008 */ insert into device_timestamp (deviceTimestampReason, loggedIn, reason, timestamp, id) values (0, 1, 'test', '2017-05-23 19:17:00', 77);
webadmin - 2017-05-23 19:17:05,008 [main] TRACE com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger - send() packet payload:
host: 'localhost' threadId: '1046'
87 00 00 00 03 69 6e 73     . . . . . i n s 
65 72 74 20 69 6e 74 6f     e r t . i n t o 
20 64 65 76 69 63 65 5f     . d e v i c e _ 
74 69 6d 65 73 74 61 6d     t i m e s t a m 
70 20 28 64 65 76 69 63     p . ( d e v i c 
65 54 69 6d 65 73 74 61     e T i m e s t a 
6d 70 52 65 61 73 6f 6e     m p R e a s o n 
2c 20 6c 6f 67 67 65 64     , . l o g g e d 
49 6e 2c 20 72 65 61 73     I n , . r e a s 
6f 6e 2c 20 74 69 6d 65     o n , . t i m e 
73 74 61 6d 70 2c 20 69     s t a m p , . i 
64 29 20 76 61 6c 75 65     d ) . v a l u e 
73 20 28 30 2c 20 31 2c     s . ( 0 , . 1 , 
20 27 74 65 73 74 27 2c     . ' t e s t ' , 
20 27 32 30 31 37 2d 30     . ' 2 0 1 7 - 0 
35 2d 32 33 20 31 39 3a     5 - 2 3 . 1 9 : 
31 37 3a 30 30 27 2c 20     1 7 : 0 0 ' , . 
37 37 29                    7 7 )
```

Comment: `loggedIn` seems to not be set as well

Comment: Assuming you're having Hibernate create your tables. Can you add the DDL from the table create statement?

Comment: Indeed, using the eclipse debugger, I've traced things down to the point that the SQL statement command buffer has been prepared. The buffer does not contain the fractional seconds. Now to backtrack in attempt to find who's doing it.

Comment: Doing deep tracing on the app, I find that the com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement::serverSupportsFracSecs = false. That apparently causes the timestamp that is placed in the insert statement to not contain the fractional seconds. Now off to figure out how to get that working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By switching from the MySQL connector to the MariaDB connector, the problem was solved. As I remember, in the earlier days of MariaDB there was no MariaDB connector and you had to use the MySQL connector. Apparently that is no longer the case. If you're using MariaDB, then it looks like the MariaDB connector is required.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem goes back to the source of the data.

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), NOW(3);
+---------------------+-------------------------+
| NOW()               | NOW(3)                  |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 2017-05-23 07:39:29 | 2017-05-23 07:39:29.110 |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
```

My point is, if the source does not have milliseconds, then `.000` is supplied during the insert.

Also, why generate the time in python?  As you see, MySQL is happy to generate the times (to up to 6 decimal places).

If you need a uniform time for multiple SQL statements, then you can capture it once, then reuse:

```
mysql> SELECT @ts := NOW(6);
+----------------------------+
| @ts := NOW(6)              |
+----------------------------+
| 2017-05-23 07:43:35.584183 |
+----------------------------+
mysql> SELECT @ts, NOW(6);
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| @ts                        | NOW(6)                     |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 2017-05-23 07:43:35.584183 | 2017-05-23 07:43:53.821409 |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
mysql> SELECT @ts, NOW(6);
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| @ts                        | NOW(6)                     |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 2017-05-23 07:43:35.584183 | 2017-05-23 07:43:55.570200 |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Caveat:  I think version 5.6.4 is when fractional seconds was first fully implemented.

**Closer test**

Using 10.0.28:

```
mysql> create table now3 (dt datetime(3), ts timestamp(3));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into now3 (dt,        ts)
                 values (now(),     now()),
                        (curdate(), curdate()),
                        (now(3),    now(3));
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
mysql> insert into now3 (dt, ts)
                 values ('2017-05-23 19:19:13.123',
                         '2017-05-23 19:19:13.123');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from now3;
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| dt                      | ts                      |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2017-05-23 19:19:13.000 | 2017-05-23 19:19:13.000 | -- NOW() has mo ms
| 2017-05-23 00:00:00.000 | 2017-05-23 00:00:00.000 | -- CURDATE() has no time
| 2017-05-23 19:19:13.842 | 2017-05-23 19:19:13.842 | -- NOW(3) worked
| 2017-05-23 19:19:13.123 | 2017-05-23 19:19:13.123 | -- from string
+-------------------------+-------------------------+

mysql> select @@version;
+--------------------------+
| @@version                |
+--------------------------+
| 10.0.28-MariaDB-1~jessie |
+--------------------------+
```

So... I guess that the data coming in is a problem.  Can you dump the actual SQL?

Comment: If you look at the timestamps in the trace data, they are indeed fractional seconds but are being truncated. And as to generating the timestamps, I have events that are generated by the system that I need to store the timestamp that has been provided in the event.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: mysql-connector-java 5.1.41 for MariaDB -- Server version: 10.0.21-MariaDB Homebrew

Comment: Appended SQL to original post.

Comment: (I've done all I can -- vindicate MySQL/MariaDB.)  Time for a spring/hibernate expert to weigh in.  Or maybe you could use `NOW(3)` in sql instead of Java?